# Error when Deploying Asp.Net Core app with multiple projects with Cloud Foundry

Tags: asp.net-core, cloud-foundry

I'm a total novice at cloud foundry and my organisation has asked me to look into deploying using cloud foundry. I've created a very basic Blazor App as shown below.

[Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owe5o.png)

When I try to deploy it I get the error message below saying that the App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase.

[Command Line Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXgAF.png)

I've tracked the issue down and it appears that adding the line 'using DataLibrary;' causes the error. If I remove it then the Blazor App is deployed.

[Using DataLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkU7f.png)

The code in the buildpack file is:

```
dotnet-core:
  sdk: 3.1
```

The code in the manifest file is:

```
applications:
name: MarkTestDeploy
memory: 64M
buildpacks:
- dotnet_core_buildpack
```

How do I get an App with multiple projects to deploy? There's obviously something I'm missing but I'm struggling to work out what.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: In the screenshot of the command line output, the "Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache..." is not from the buildpack. That's a failure of the cf cli to fetch the log output, so it's not really possible to tell what is happening in the app. It could be for all we know deploying just fine. I would suggest you see if you can get that fixed. You might need to adjust your proxy settings, or run the cf cli from a different point on the network or even try using another client like Apps Manager, if you have one available. You need to get the actual logs though to understand what happend.

Comment: As to `using DataLibrary` causing problems, I don't see how that would impact the ability to fetch logs, as that's part of the platform not your app. I would suggest you check the docs for multi-project builds here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/dotnet-core/index.html#multiple-projects. You can also build locally (on a Linux VM) and push the built binary. That's always an option.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll raise the issue of the 'Failed to retrieve logs from Log Cache' error messages with my manager and see if he can get that resolved. The main issue is the 'using DataLibrary;' causing the 'App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase'. I've looked through the link you sent and had a few questions. 1. Is there a specific name to give the .deployment file e.g. buildpack.deployment? 2. Is the deployment file placed in the same folder as the buildpack and manifest files? 3. I don't have access to a linux vm is there any way to get the built binary on my windows machine?

Comment: `1. Is there a specific name to give the .deployment file e.g. buildpack.deployment?` -> the full and complete name of the file should be `.deployment` nothing else.  `2. Is the deployment file placed in the same folder as the buildpack and manifest files?` -> Yes. It should go in the directory from which you're running `cf push` or the directory that you have pointed to with `cf push -p` or the `path` argument in manifest.yml.

Comment: `3. I don't have access to a linux vm is there any way to get the built binary on my windows machine?` -> Docker would be one option. Possibly the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) but I haven't tried that. Ultimately, it would need to produce a Linux binary not an exe when you build.